# Laravel not making Guzzle HTTP POST request correctly

Tags: laravel, magento2, guzzle

I am working on a megento integration and trying to get the admin access token by making a post request with form data. I tested the route out on Postman and it worked correctly:
[image]

However, when I tried to implement the same request in Laravel with Guzzle Http Client, it seem just cannot make the request properly as if the form data post body is not being recognized, and it keeps showing me errors saying the field values are required. Here is my request:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post($request['magento_domain'] . '/rest/V1/integration/admin/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => $magento_admin_username,
        'password' => $magento_admin_password
    ], [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ]
]);
```

and then this is the error I keep getting:
[image]

Update: I had also tried the request like this, it throws the same error:

```
$response = $client->post($request['magento_domain'] . '/rest/V1/integration/admin/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => $magento_admin_username,
        'password' => $magento_admin_password
    ]
]);
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Content-Type: application/json" request header is incorrect when sending a form-data body.

Just remove it, Guzzle automatically adds the correct Content-Type when using "form_params". Just JSON is wrong because the body is obviously not JSON.

I am using a JSON request in production successfully:

```php
$res = $this->client->request('POST', 'https://.../rest/V1/integration/admin/token', [
  'headers' => [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'content-type' => 'application/json'
  ],
  'json' => [
    'username' => config('app.shopUser'),
    'password' => config('app.shopPw')
  ]
]);
```

Or try using "multipart" instead of "form_params" - this should send a `multipart/form-data` request which is what Postman means with "form-data".
"form_params" is equivalent to "x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: It cannot be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, because when I make the request is form-url-encode, the response says: "Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded". so it has to be form data. and the reason why I set content type to be application/json was because that's what Postman sent

Comment: No matter what header you set, if you use "form_params" the body is encoded as x-www-form already: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params "Used to send an application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request." - I'll check how to send a form-data request.